# Non-linear corrections to the Oseen-Frank free energy density

Tags: condensed-matter, soft-matter, liquid-crystal

A nematic liquid crystal is essentially a fluid of long, rod-like molecules whose average orientation is dictated by a vector field $\mathbf {\hat {n}} $. The so-called Frank-Oseen (free) energy (density) associated with deformations from the uniform state is  given by:

$${\displaystyle {\mathcal {F}}={\frac {1}{2}}K_{1}(\nabla \cdot \mathbf {\hat {n}} )^{2}+{\frac {1}{2}}K_{2}(\mathbf {\hat {n}} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf {\hat {n}} )^{2}+{\frac {1}{2}}K_{3}(\mathbf {\hat {n}} \times \nabla \times \mathbf {\hat {n}} )^{2},}$$

being $K_{1,2,3}$ constants.

> Are there physical situations/phenomena that introduce corrections to $\mathcal {F}$ with higher powers of $\mathbf {\hat {n}} $ ?

From the point of view of a field theory it would be a natural step to introduce higher order terms describing self-interactions of the field, but I have no notice of physical relevance of one such a term.